# Removing borders from QWidgets in a QGraphicsGridLayout

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qgraphicsscene

I currently have a QGraphicsScene that I am using with a QGraphicsGridLayout. I am trying to align QWidgets (QLabels and a custom graph QWidget) on this grid layout, and then export it to a QPrinter for pdf export.

The problem I'm having is that I have these grey divider lines between the QLabels that I can't seem to get rid of. I have tried settings spacing in the layout to 0, margins to 0, all the different properties of the QLabel palette, etc. all to no avail. Here's the relevant code:

main class:

```
QLabel lbl("some text");
lbl.setAutoFillBackground(true);
QPalette pal = lbl.palette();
pal.setColor(QPalette::Window, Qt::white);
lbl.setPalette(pal);
lbl.setFrameStyle(QFrame::NoFrame);
reportlayout->addWidget(&lbl);
reportlayout->generatePDF(reportfilename);
```

reportlayout class:

```
gridlayout->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);
gridlayout->setSpacing(0);

QGraphicsWidget* page = new QGraphicsWidget();
page->setLayout(gridlayout);
scene->addItem(page);
printer->setOutputFileName(filename);
painter->begin(printer);
scene->render(painter);
painter->end();
```

I have a feeling that it is the layout doing this, as the lines are between cells in the grid - but the layout doesn't have any color properties and I couldn't find anything to do with divider lines.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried stylesheets?

For example,

```
setStylesheet("QLabel { border:0px solid black; }");
```

You must investigate all possible selectors till find which one introduces the border.

Comment: Yes I have. I saw a similar suggestion on another stackoverflow post. I've tried all the stylesheet properties I can think of with respect to QLabel, this is one of the reasons why I think it's being caused by the layout.

Comment: So maybe there is a selector for that but on the `QGraphicsWidget`